# Please explain how to install shadowsocks http obfs in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, server, partitioning

---

- Please explain how to install (shadowsocks http
  obfs) in (ubuntu) 18.04

I couldn’t find the right way anywhere

---

Answer (score 2):

Information on how to install Shadowsocks **CLIENT** is here: https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-qt5/wiki/Installation and here: https://github.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-client/

Further information on how to install the Shadowsocks Command-line client is provided here: https://shadowsocks.org/en/download/clients.html, place where you can see this under the "Linux" section.

### Command-line Client

```
apt-get install shadowsocks-libev
cpan Net::Shadowsocks
```

## AppImage

A ready-to-use binary (AppImage) can be downloaded here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-releases/master/client/stable/Outline-Client.AppImage after which you can simply give the file the proper execution permissions in order to run it via terminal or GUI.

But, if you mean a different "Shadowsocks", you can let us know what have you tried before asking, or -at least- give us the proper application you may wish to install, edit your question, add the details and I'm sure you will receive better support answers.